# SQL query doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run the following query but it doesn't seem to work properly and an error comes back with:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\VACANCY\pages\search\booking2.php on line 83
```

Which is while:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($Result)
```

All I want to is to return the chosen `JOB_TITLE` AND `LOCATION` from my `jobs` table. Please any help would be great as I have spent hours trying to solve it.

```
<?php
    $Query = "(SELECT FROM jobs  " .
        "WHERE jobs.JOB_TITLE ='$_POST[JOB_TITLE]' " .
        "AND jobs.LOCATION = '$_POST[LOCATION]')";
    $Result = mysqli_query($DB, $Query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($Result))
    {
        echo $row['JOB_TITLE'] . " " . $row['LOCATION'];
        echo "<br />";
    }   
?>
```

Comment: You are not selecting anything. You need something like `SELECT Job_title, Location FROM jobs WHERE ...`

Comment: @GarethD I was just about to post that same response =p

Comment: I did post that :) but your clearly beat me

Comment: @alan k It's easy to miss, but you can edit your question. Rather than creating multiple versions of the same question, you can add to or change your question based on comments and suggested answers. This allows the people who have taken an interest in helping you to follow your progress and offer additional suggestions based on your feedback. More info here: [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 4):

You need to add something after SELECT. For example, SELECT JOB_TITLE, LOCATION FROM...

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is "SELECT FROM", so you don't indicate what you want to select. If you query "SELECT * FROM" then all fields will be selected and the query will work.

But please be aware that your code is very insecure. The POST value from the search form can be manipulated by an attacker and the query can be used e.g. to truncate the whole table. Read more at http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php.